# How to calculate the integral of a fourier trasfom

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, fast-fourier-transform

I have to calculate this integral :

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat G(\omega)e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}\omega}d\omega$

($\hat G(\omega)$ is the Fourier trasform)
with:

$G:x\in \Bbb{R}\to \begin{cases}
g(x),  & \text{if |x| $\leq$ $\pi$} \\
0, & \text{if |x| $\gt$$\pi$}
\end{cases}$

and:
$g:x \in[-\pi,\pi[\to \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if |x| $\ge$ $\frac{\pi}{2}$} \\
e^x, & \text{if |x| $\lt$$\frac{\pi}{2}$}
\end{cases}$

Comment: It seems to be you want almost the inverse Fourier Transform, yet that denominator $\;2\;$ in the exponent of  $\;e\;$, though I guess it depends on the interval of periodicity. Then you'd recover $\;G(x)\;$ with the first integral.

Comment: Is there any initiative on how you started the problem? Or are you confused about the entire problem? Math SE is not a place to ask for solutions for your homework.